# How to store objects being returned from Async methods?

Tags: c#, .net, api, async-await, task

So I have two classes:

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public EmployeeData[] data { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeData
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string employee_name { get; set; }
        public int employee_salary { get; set; }
        public int employee_age { get; set; }
        public string profile_image { get; set; }
    }
```

And I am trying to call to a public API:

```
// using Newtonsoft.Json;
// using RestSharp;
public static async Task<Employee> getEmployeeData()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/"); // Base url
        var request = new RestRequest("employees");
        var response = client.Execute(request);

        Employee result = null;
        string rawResponse = "";
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            rawResponse = response.Content;
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Fact>(rawResponse); // JSON to C# Object
        }
        return result ;
    }
```

Then I am trying to store whatever is returned by `getEmployeeData()` in a variable called `employee` inside main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee employee = GetCatFact();
    }
```

BUT It says: "cannot implicitly convert type 'system.threading.tasks.task' to 'Employee'"

So how do I make it so that I can store `getEmployeeData()` inside the variable `employee` without changing `getEmployeeData()`?

Comment: you need to await the call : `await GetCatFact()`

Comment: You'll also need to make your Main method async - `static async Task Main(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark your `Main` method as `async` one (available since [C# 7.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main)) and call `await` on the `GetCatFact` (or `getEmployeeData` your question is a bit inconsistent):

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
     Employee employee = await GetCatFact(); // or getEmployeeData
}
```

Related:

1. [asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)
2. [`async` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async)
3. [`await` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await)

Answer (score 0):

`getEmployeeData` is async method, so you need to wait for result:

```
var employeeData = await getEmployeeData();
```

There is another option

```
var employeeData = getEmployeeData().Result;
```